# Python JSON/Dict Converting Key:Pair to Key=Pair

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am new to coding in Python and I am trying to convert key:pair's to key=pairs but only in certain parts of a JSON/Dictionary hierarchy.

I currently have this:

```
 {'AdditionalInfo': 'string',
    'AmiVersion': 'string',
    'Applications': [{
                'AdditionalInfo': {
                    'string': 'string'
                },
                'Args': ['string'],
                'Name': 'string',
                'Version': 'string'
            }]}
```

And I am trying to get the below:

```
 {'AdditionalInfo' = 'string',
    'AmiVersion' = 'string',
    'Applications' = [{
                'AdditionalInfo': {
                    'string': 'string'
                },
                'Args': ['string'],
                'Name': 'string',
                'Version': 'string'
            }]}
```

The original file is in JSON, so the quotes would be double but I have changed these in my logic. So far I have tried json.loads, json.dumps, dict(). All of those continue to provide the first example above.

Comment: Why is it necessary? How will you parse the file back, with custom parser?

Comment: Your  desired format is neither valid Python or JSON, so `str.replace(':', ' =')` is probably your best option, assuming that there are no colons in the keys or values.

Comment: What advantage do you get when you have `key=pairs`?

Comment: yeah, same question  @quamrana

Comment: The output you are expecting is not a valid python object. However, you can make a string in your desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own wrapper over json, to produce the `__str__` of your requirements.
Below an example program

```py
import json
class data:
    def __init__(self,text):
        self.text=text
    def __repr__(self):
        js=json.loads(self.text)
        string="{"
        for k in js:
            string+='"%s"=%s,'%(k,json.dumps(js[k]))
        return string[:-1]+"}"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()

line="""{"AdditionalInfo": "string",
    "AmiVersion": "string",
    "Applications": [{
                "AdditionalInfo": {
                    "string": "string"
                },
                "Args": ["string"],
                "Name": "string",
                "Version": "string"
            }]}"""
print(data(line))
```

Output:

```
{"AdditionalInfo"="string","AmiVersion"="string","Applications"=[{"AdditionalInfo": {"string": "string"}, "Args": ["string"], "Name": "string", "Version": "string"}]}
```